# split an apache-spark dataframe string column into multiple columns by slicing/splitting on field width values stored in a list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
+--------------------
|       unparsed_data|
+--------------------
|02020sometext5002...
|02020sometext6682...
```

I need to get it split it up into something like this

```
+--------------------
|fips  | Name     | Id ...    
+--------------------
|02020 | sometext | 5002...
|02020 | sometext | 6682...
```

I have a list like this

```
val fields = List(
  ("fips", 5),
  (“Name”, 8),
  (“Id”, 27)
  ....more fields
)
```

I need the spit to take the first 5 characters in `unparsed_data` and map it to `fips`, take the next 8 characters in `unparsed_data` and map it to `Name`, then the next 27 characters and map them to `Id` and so on.  I need the split to use/reference the filed lengths supplied in the list to do the splitting/slicing as there are allot of fields and the `unparsed_data` field is very long.

My scala is still pretty week and I assume the answer would look something like this

```
df.withColumn("temp_field", split("unparsed_data", //some regex created from the list values?)).map(i => //some mapping to the field names in the list)
```

any suggestions/ideas much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [foldLeft](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.html#foldLeft[B](z:B)(op:(B,A)=>B):B) to traverse your `fields` list to iteratively create columns from the original DataFrame using 
[substring](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@substring(str:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,pos:Int,len:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Column).  It applies regardless of the size of the `fields` list:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
  ("02020sometext5002"),
  ("03030othrtext6003"),
  ("04040moretext7004")
).toDF("unparsed_data")

val fields = List(
  ("fips", 5),
  ("name", 8),
  ("id", 4)
)

val resultDF = fields.foldLeft( (df, 1) ){ (acc, field) =>
    val newDF = acc._1.withColumn(
      field._1, substring($"unparsed_data", acc._2, field._2)
    )
    (newDF, acc._2 + field._2)
  }._1.
  drop("unparsed_data")

resultDF.show
// +-----+--------+----+
// | fips|    name|  id|
// +-----+--------+----+
// |02020|sometext|5002|
// |03030|othrtext|6003|
// |04040|moretext|7004|
// +-----+--------+----+
```

Note that a `Tuple2[DataFrame, Int]` is used as the accumulator for `foldLeft` to carry both the iteratively transformed DataFrame and next offset position for `substring`.

Comment: I have to think about this. I knew u would come the fold and that it was somehow possible. I get the impression that scala allows virtually everything.

Answer (score 1):

This can get you going. Depending on your needs it can get more and more complicated with variable lengths etc. which you do not state. But you can I think use column list.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
       ("12334sometext999")
       ).toDF("X")

 val df2 = df.selectExpr("substring(X, 0, 5)", "substring(X, 6,8)", "substring(X, 14,3)")

 df2.show
```

Gives in this case (you can rename cols again):

```
+------------------+------------------+-------------------+
|substring(X, 0, 5)|substring(X, 6, 8)|substring(X, 14, 3)|
+------------------+------------------+-------------------+
|             12334|          sometext|                999|
+------------------+------------------+-------------------+
```